# Articles in "The peptide chain is known as the backbone, and the "R" groups are known as side chains."

Tags: articles

From [Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/aminoacids/proteinstruct.html#top):

> A protein chain (with the N-terminal on the left) will therefore look like this:
>
> [image]
>
> The "R" groups come from the 20 amino acids which occur in proteins. The peptide chain is known as **the backbone**, and the "R" groups are known as **side chains**.

Can we say "as **the** side chains" instead? After all, there's 'the' before 'backbone'.

Comment: You *could* add "the", but it sounds more correct as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can say "the side chains" too.

However, there is probably a reason for using "the" only for the backbone; in a protein chain there is only one backbone (so it's clear which ine you refer to), but there are many side chains, possibly of different types. So "the side chains" may leave ambiguity as to which group of side chains you refer to.

Comment: But can I say "the side chains"? With plural "chains"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to write. I'll correct.